# Php search with multiple values

Tags: php, database

i try to make a search system which has multiple inputs. I tried to to select the data in query and that it supose to add the aditional data if it exist but it dont do that. i messed it up and dont know how to fix it. The data from my other file gets there. I checked it. Did anyone know what i did wrong?

```
<?php
    $connect= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "website");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM data";
    $sort = " date DESC"
    if(isset($_GET["search"])){
        $keywordsearch = $connect->escape_string($_GET['search']);
        $query .= " WHERE name like '%$keywordsearch%'";

        if(isset($_GET['tag'])){
            $keywordtag = $connect->escape_string($_GET['tag']);
            $query .= " AND tag like '%$keywordtag%'";  
            $query .= " ORDER BY $sort";
        }
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['name']."<br>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Its worse than you think! Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Most obvious error is `$sort = " date DESC"` :) Missing a semi colon

Comment: my problem is that i can input the tag variable and if the tag variable is something that is not included in the database it shows nothing and i get no results but if it is included into the db than it shows all results and not only the results that match

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating an array of the data passed in and using that array you can control all the other requirements to build a query and pass parameters using a Parameterised and bound query

```
$_GET = ['search'=> 'fluff', 'tag'=>'easy'];


$connect= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "website");
$query = "SELECT * FROM data";
$sort = " ORDER BY date DESC";

if(isset($_GET["search"])){
    $query .= " WHERE name like ?";
    $vals[] = '%' . $_GET["search"] . '%';
}

if(isset($_GET['tag'])){
    $query .= " OR tag like ?";  
    $vals[] = '%' . $_GET["tag"] . '%';
}

$query .= $sort;

$types = str_repeat('s', count($vals));

$stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$vals);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['name']."<br>";
}
```

RESULT:

```
easy peasy<br>
fluff fluff<br>
```

From your comment:  *problem is that i can input the tag variable and if the tag variable is something that is not included in the database it shows nothing*

That is because you are using an `AND` rather than an `OR` in the query. I corrected that also